# Substitution of an expression into another expression

Tags: replacement

I'm trying the following Mathematica command to simplify an expression by substitution of a known constant, but it's not performing the substitution. Any ideas why?

```
FullSimplify[((krRA + aRA) (kfRL L aRL + aR (krRL + aRL)))/(kfRA aRA (krRL + aRL)), Assumptions -> kmL == (aR (krRL + aRL))/(kfRL aRL), Assumptions -> {kfRL > 0, aRL > 0, kfRL aRL > 0}]
```

Answer (score 2):

**write your equation like this with assumption**

```
eq = FullSimplify[((krRA + aRA) (kfRL L aRL + 
aR (krRL + aRL)))/(kfRA aRA (krRL + aRL)), 
Assumptions -> {kfRL > 0, aRL > 0, kfRL aRL > 0}]
```

[image]

**Solve you substitution with respect to a variable available in the eq! let's choose aR to represent equation with respect to them so we substitute them in first equation eq.**

```
sub = Solve[kmL == (aR (krRL + aRL))/(kfRL aRL), aR] // 
Flatten /. Rule -> Equal
```

[image]

**use replacement or substitution as follow to get your simplified expression**

```
eq /. sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of this technique of using replacement rules to perform substitutions. But I'm wondering why the method of using the Simplify command to do this doesn't work. According to the documentation, the Simplify command should be able to perform the substitution.

Comment: @AbedAlnaif I suspect the reason your method does not work with `Simplify` is that you are expecting `Simplify` to replace something small and simple with something larger and more complicated. I suspect if you used your same `Simplify` method in reverse and gave it the larger and more complicated expression with your assumption that it would happily replace the larger expression with `kfRL` That is because it is trying to find the smallest and simplest form of the result. Does that seem understandable?